# Error connection

Tags: android, connection

I have problem with http connection, this is my logcat:

```
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fsi.sizeer.mcw/fsi.sizeer.mcw.McwActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:477)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:277)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:249)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:69)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:304)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:292)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1038)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:523)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:645)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at fsi.sizeer.mcw.McwActivity.coversFileParse(McwActivity.java:79)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at fsi.sizeer.mcw.McwActivity.onCreate(McwActivity.java:71)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  ... 11 more
```

This is my method:

```
public void coversFileParse(String URL) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = dBuilder.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nodeListIssue = document.getElementsByTagName("Issue");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeListIssue.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeListIssue.item(i);
            Element elementMain = (Element) node;
            NamedNodeMap nodeListText = elementMain.getAttributes();
            Log.v(TAG, ""+nodeListText);
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have Internet permission and Network connection, I have restart my emulator a few times and nothink, can You help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two lines actually let you know what the error is:

```
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
11-10 11:31:22.036: E/AndroidRuntime(496):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1077)
```

It seems like you have enabled `StrictMode`, causing it to throw an Exception whenever you utilize the GUI-thread in the wrong way (ie do network requests like you're doing above).

The solution would be to start using `AsyncTask`s, so that your network traffic gets sent and processed on another "thread":

```
public FileParseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        //Show dialogs here or similar

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void ... arg0) {

        //Do your actual network operations here, as well as parsing

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        //Remove dialogs if any, and other "GUI"-updates that follow your parsing-

    }
}
```

Hope that helps you get an understandning of why the error occurs, and how you can prevent it in the future.

Comment: THX, firstly, it's should be public class extends. When I call new FileParseTask().execute(); it's execute two times, why ?

Comment: Hey Dawid - are you sure that you're not looping the `new FileParseTask().execute()` or something like that?